# MarkLogic: Trying to understand error "Node has complex type with non-mixed complex content"

Tags: xslt, marklogic

I'm getting this error during pipeline processing of an xml document, the processing does an xslt transform.  It appears to be telling me that the document is in some way invalid, however the document passes validation against the xsd in Oxygen.

First, the error is not telling me the line number in the offending data file, just the line number in the pipeline xqy file, from what I can tell.

Second: The error is grammatically non-sensical to me: It seems to say that a node in the document is defined as a complex type, but that content in the document is non-mixed...why would that matter?  Most content is non-mixed, right?  So non-mixed content is as I see it sort of the norm in most xml that I see.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The error can also occur when some function is expecting a more simple value as argument, but receiving complex element types.

Actually, searching in the archives at http://marklogic.markmail.org/ the error seems to be coming from fn:data() if it is passed 'too' complex values to put it briefly. I think the message is meant to say that the node that is being passed in doesn't have a typed value. See also here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-data

If you provide the full error message, we might be able to help you out..

Comment: Thanks grtjn for your work, let me start tracking this down, this sounds helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The document is likely valid, but it doesn't conform to expectations in your XSLT code.  Without seeing code and document, muy hunch is that the XSLT is expecting the matching document node to be an element (or similar) but it is an attribute or text node.

Comment: Thanks Eric. It seems that I'm not reaching the xsl transform process; the error message seems to be ML-specific which is making things really hard since I can't interpret it and it doesn't appear to be documented anywhere.